# subclass not updating variable taken from base class

Tags: java

Why is my output not giving expected result i.e. `25`? I know my question is silly but I am new in Java programming.
the output is

```
run:
5
0
0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

But according to me expected answer is 5 as I have passed 5 in arguement.

```
class A {
    int a;

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }    
}

class B extends A {    
    public int multi() {
        int multi = a * a;
        System.out.println(multi);
        return multi;
    }    
}

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj1 = new A();
        obj1.setA(5);
        B obj2 = new B();
        int c = obj2.multi();
        System.out.println(c);        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting the code in your question - this is *horrible* to read at the moment.

Comment: I've already added an answer - now, is there any reason you can't fix up your question to be more readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why output is not giving expected result i.e. 25

Because you have two different objects, each with an independent `a` field. You're setting the value to 5 in one object, but then calling `multi()` on the other object, so it's using the default value of the field (0).

If you use the same object for both parts, you'll get the right answer:

```
B obj2 = new B();
A obj1 = obj2; // Now obj1 and obj2 refer to the same object
obj1.setA(5);
System.out.println(obj2.multi());
```